# Translate SQLite to Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to get the all albums with the average voting.

```
SELECT a.*, avg(v._mark) AS voting from musicwebapp_album AS a LEFT JOIN musicwebapp_vote AS v ON v.album_id = a.id GROUP BY a.id;
```

I actually don't know how to to do it with django.

This are my modles:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Artist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)

class Album(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    genre = models.ForeignKey(Genre, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, default=None)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, default=None)
    lend_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    cover = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, default=None)

class Vote(models.Model):
    _mark = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    voted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False)

    def setMark(self, mark):
        if mark <= 0:
            return -1

        if mark > 5:
            return -1

        self._mark = mark
        return sef._mark

    def getMark(self):
        return self._mark
```

I am using django 2.1.2 with python 3.6.6.

Thanks for your help

Comment: please provide your model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your model Vote has a foreign key to Album (I think you missed it) as album:

```
class Vote(models.Model):
    _mark = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    voted_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can write as:

```
qs = Album.objects.annotate(voting=Avg('vote___mark'))
```

This will give you all the attributes for album and average of _mark field of Votes model.

Now each album object of the queryset will have voting attribute and can be achieved as:

```
for obj in qs:
    average_vote = obj.voting
```

It is mentioned in the [docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards)

Comment: How do I access the average sum ?

Comment: Thanks very much :-)